# A simple proof for $\mathrm{seg}^nA=\mathrm{conv}A$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

For $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ show that $\mathrm{seg}^nA=\mathrm{conv}A$

$\mathrm{conv}A$ is a convex "envelope" around $A$

$\mathrm{sgn}A$ denotes the union of all segments with ends at points from $A$, and $\mathrm{seg}^kA=\mathrm{seg}\left ( \mathrm{seg}^{k-1}A \right )$

**My attempt:**

If $\left \{ A_i \right \}_{i\in I}$ a family of subsets $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\left ( \cup _{i\in I}A_i \right )^*=\cap _{i\in I}A_i^*$

If $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}^n$$$ is a segment, then $[a,b]^*=\left \{ a,b \right \}^*=a^*\cap b^*$. In particular, if $a=0$ and $\left \| b \right \|=1$, then $[0,b]^*=b^*$ $-$ containing $0$ the half-space bounded by the hyperplane $\pi$ perpendicular to $[0,b]$ and passing through $b$

Let's go on to prove the assertion of this point. To do this, just check that $A^*=\left ( \mathrm{seg}A \right )^*$. Let's represent $A$ as $A=\cup _{\left \{ a,b \right \}\subset A}\left \{ a,b \right \}$, then we have
$$A^*=\left ( \bigcup_{\left \{ a,b \right \}\subset A}^{}\left \{ a,b \right \} \right )^*=\bigcap_{\left \{ a,b \right \}\subset A}^{}\left \{ a,b \right \}^*=\bigcap_{\left \{ a,b \right \}\subset A}^{}[a,b]^*=\left ( \bigcup_{\left \{ a,b \right \}\subset A}^{}[a,b] \right )^*=\left ( \mathrm{seg}A \right )^*$$

*Question: Can I prove it in a simpler way? It seems to me that I have proved too difficult*

Comment: It is not clear what superscript $*$ means.

Comment: The traditional way would be to just show that anything in $\textrm{sgn}^n(A)$ is a convex combination of elements of $A$.

Comment: What's the traditional way?

Comment: Can we look at this method ?

Comment: depends on the definition of $\textrm{conv}$ from your class, but by "convex combinatoin" I just mean a linear combination where all the weights are positive and they sum-to-one. It should be an algebra exercise to show that any point in $\textrm{seg}^n\,A$ is a convex combo; and the algebra moves should be equivalences, which would provide set-equality.

Comment: btw I still don't understand your argument. what does $*$ mean?!